# SQL query find dates in range of relation to another date

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying query and table to find a incident opened date that is within 2 weeks after a user start date.

I have a table like this

```
ID | StartDate               | OpenedDate
---|-------------------------|---------------------
1  | 2014-01-02 05:44:47.000 | 2014-01-14 00:00:00.000
2  | 2011-01-02 13:35:01.000 | 2012-07-09 00:00:00.000
3  | 2011-01-02 13:35:01.000 | 2011-01-10 00:00:00.000
4  | 2011-01-02 13:35:01.000 | 2012-07-09 00:00:00.000
5  | 2011-01-02 13:35:01.000 | 2012-07-09 00:00:00.000
```

I would only want lines 1 and 3 since StartDate is within 2 weeks of the opendate

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    StartDate,
    OpenedDate
FROM
    mytable
WHERE
    OpenedDate >= DATEADD(d, -14, StartDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
ID,
StartDate,
OpenedDate
FROM
mytable
WHERE
datediff(wk,getdate(),startdate)<=2
```